# Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster after Setup Upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, elasticsearch, magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade

I have upgraded magento to 2.4.5 and when i ran setup upgrade command I received this error

"Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster".

Elastic Search is running, I have checked. Also tried to restart es by

sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch

but not working. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

If you need error free access the site/terminal. Just try to disable given below modules

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch7
```

Note: Before Disable module. You should check the first server/hosting provider side elasticsearch enable or disable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your elasticsearch engine is installed locally (on `localhost`) and is enabled/active
(I also assume the version of your elastic search is 7)

this query will fix your issue:

```
update core_config_data set value='localhost' where path='catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname';
```

If your use docker or your architecture is different than a local lemp/lamp stack then you need to find the hostname where your elasticsearch is installed and modify the query accordingly

Comment: Hey I run the above command but still issue not resolved

Comment: np, thanks for the feedback. Hope you get it sorted

Comment: Yes I resolved it, It was due to different port number of ES in env file so i removed the port in env file, and now its working